# Select Into a table on server1 from server2 without using 'Linked Servers'

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get all the records from one table into another table but these tables (which are identical) are on separate servers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the goal of avoiding linked servers? This is typically how you set up communication between servers (hence the name).

Comment: One time. Can do everything (create read update delete) on both servers and databases EXCEPT create a linked server because I am not a sysadmin (these are remote servers) and I cannot get those privs. I guess I just found it silly that I can do all these operations on both but there is no easy way for me to get one table's data to another.

Comment: @RossBarbish adding your last comment to the question would make it a more sound question and indicates the goal.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is just a one time transfer, the quickest method would be to use **SQL Server Import and Export Wizard** (Right click on the database -
    Tasks - Export Data)

And [here is](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/D/D/8DD7BDBA-CEF7-4D8E-8C16-D9F69527F909/ENU/x64/SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe) SQL Server Management Studio Express (64-bit) if you don't have one already.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant `INSERT INTO Server2.dbo.TableA Select FROM Server1.dbo.Table` and not `SELECT INTO Server2.dbo.TableA FROM Server1.dbo.Table`

You can use [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx)

> This method is an alternative to accessing tables in a linked server
>   and is a one-time, ad hoc method of connecting and accessing remote
>   data by using OLE DB. For more frequent references to OLE DB data
>   sources, use linked servers instead. For more information, see Linked
>   Servers (Database Engine). The OPENROWSET function can be referenced
>   in the FROM clause of a query as if it were a table name. The
>   OPENROWSET function can also be referenced as the target table of an
>   INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement, subject to the capabilities of
>   the OLE DB provider.

You may rule it out though because of whatever constraint you have that's stopping you from using a linked server.

If that's the case you'll need to use an ETL tool like SSIS or write a process in a client tool that does it without `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax.